# Order of finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If G is a finite group and the order of every element is some power of 2. Then what can we say about the order of G? Is it also some power of 2?

Comment: Yes. This follows from Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I can see the order of G is even, but why it is some power of 2?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks! I see now.

Comment: In particular, $o(G)=2^n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Here $o(G)$ denotes the *order of $G$*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Cauchy's Theorem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory),]) if $p$ is a prime that divides the order of $G$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$. Thus the order of $G$ cannot have an odd prime divisor.

Comment: Opps, you are right.